# How do you set the state of an array using useState?

Tags: reactjs

i am trying to add an array to a state using useState from a database and it's not working

```
    const [state, setstate] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get("/api/reviews").then((response) => {
            console.log(response.data.data);
            setstate(response.data.data);
            console.log(state);
        });
    }, []);
```

the console.log(response.data.data) returns the array properly so the data is there. but its not being put into the testimonials state for whatever reason. I've tried setting up all the proper fields first as an initial state. I have tried using a callback function inside of setTestimonials but nothing has worked.

Any advice would be appreciated!!

Comment: you have to provide a tiny bit more of your code, e.g. where the stuff for testimonials is defined?

Answer (score 1):

That's because you set state with `setTestimonials` function but on the top of code you provided, we can see that function's name is `setstate` not `setTestimonials`.

```
    const [state, setstate] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get("/api/reviews").then((response) => {
            console.log(response.data.data);
            setTestimonials(response.data.data); // This should be setstate(response.data.data)
            console.log(state);
        });
    }, []);
```

Comment: sorry. that was a typo. it is the same function name in my code

Comment: Then it happens because `setstate` is asynchronous function and `console.log()` function is executed before setting the state

Comment: check the value of state in react devtools